# How to generate a fully connected subgraph from node list using python's networkx module

Tags: python, networkx

I need to generate a fully connected subgraph with [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/), starting from the list of nodes I want to connect. Basically, I want all the nodes in the list I pass to the function to be all connected with each other.

I wonder if there is any built-in function to achieve this (which I haven't found)? 
Or should I think of some algorithm?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know of any method which does this, but you can easily mimic the complete_graph() method of networkx and slightly change it(almost like a builtin):

```
import networkx
import itertools

def complete_graph_from_list(L, create_using=None):
    G = networkx.empty_graph(len(L),create_using)
    if len(L)>1:
        if G.is_directed():
            edges = itertools.permutations(L,2)
        else:
            edges = itertools.combinations(L,2)
        G.add_edges_from(edges)
    return G

S = complete_graph_from_list(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
print S.edges()
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, I should have looked for these permutations/combinations functions :)

Comment: This worked for me when I replaced `n>1` with `len(L)>1`

Comment: There are direct methods to do this using `nx.complete_graph` and `nx.relabel_nodes`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 14):

There is a function for creating fully connected (i.e. complete) graphs, nameley `complete_graph`.

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.complete_graph(10)
```

It takes an integer argument (the number of nodes in the graph) and thus you cannot control the node labels. I haven't found a function for doing that automatically, but with `itertools` it's easy enough:

```
from itertools import combinations

nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
edges = combinations(nodes, 2)
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(nodes)
g.add_edges_from(edges)
```

`combinations(nodes, 2)` will create 2-element tuples with all pair combinations of `nodes` which then will work as the edges in the graph.

This solution is however only valid for undirected graphs. Take a look at [zubinmehta's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651524/885443) for a more general approach.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the networkx commands to directly generate a clique with integer nodes, and then there is a simple command to relabel the nodes with any other hashable names.

```
import networkx as nx
L=["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you"]
G=nx.complete_graph(len(L))
nx.relabel_nodes(G,dict(enumerate(L)), copy = False) #if copy = True then it returns a copy.
```