# Creating list that would contain pairs of another list?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Sorry for my inability to write a question in elegant way. I hope that further text will be sufficient to understand my question.

I have a set of lists that contain from one to five members. I would like to create graph from each list.

My data:

```
data = [
['07F', '05F', '10F', '06F'],
['05T', '05F', '02T'],
['03T', '03F']
]
```

I expect that each list would result in all possible pairs of list:

```
['07F', '05F', '10F', '06F'] should become ----------->

['07F',05F']
['07F',10F']
['07F',06F']
['05F',10F']
['05F',06F']
['10F',06F']
```

The same with all next lists.

All I understand is that I have to iterate through the list, and then..?

Comment: Have a look to the `itertools` library. In particular, `itertools.combinations`

Comment: maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649673/how-to-generate-a-fully-connected-subgraph-from-node-list-using-pythons-network

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint
data = [
    ['07F', '05F', '10F', '06F'],
    ['05T', '05F', '02T'],
    ['03T', '03F']
    ] 

# Create a list of the lists of pair-wise combinations
data = [list(itertools.combinations(x,2)) for x in data]

pprint(data)
```

Comment: I get result in brackets "('01S', '07S')". How can remove them? Is there any way to get just a list?

Comment: You *do* get just a list. The display of a list includes brackets. Can you give an example of what you want the display to look like?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Yes, I can iterate the result. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools    
print [a for a in itertools.combinations(data,2)]
```

Comment: I'm afraid permutations is not the answer, really

Comment: i see, the OP only wants combinations of two, i will edit the answer