# How to generate a list with couples of random integers?

Tags: python, list, random, neural-network, networkx

I am rather new to Python and NetworkX. I need to create a list similar to `Edgelist=[(0,1),(0,3),(1,0),(1,2),(1,4),(2,1),(2,5)]`, which elements represent *the starting and ending node of an edge* (link) that is in turn part of a network.

Rather than setting them manually, I want Python to create the couples you see in the list by randomly selecting the integer values of `(start,end)` from an assigned range of values (namely, `0, 999`), which represent the node IDs. Then, I want to make sure that every node ID is included at least once in the series of (start,end) values (*this means that all my nodes will be connected to at least one other node*).

I know I could use `random.randint(0, 999)` but I don't know how to "nest" it into the creation of a list (perhaps a for loop?). I wish I had some code to show you but this is my first attempt at working with NetworkX!

**EDIT**

To give you a visual idea of what I mean, here are two images. The first is a regular network (aka lattice), and the second is a random one. The edge list of the first was created manually in order to reproduce a chess table, while the second displays an edge list which is a (manually) shuffled counterpart of the first one. **As you see, the nodes are kept in exactly the same locations.** Hope this helps a bit more. Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Networkx has many algorithms for generating random networks.  Using one of them is likely to be better than the approach you are describing, especially because there are many very different varieties of random graph that would have the property you've described..  Can you tell us a bit more about the properties you want for your network?

Comment: Thanks for asking Joel. I have already built a lattice (e.g., a regular network which length distribution is a constant value - all nodes are equidistant from each other). Now I want to build a random network out of the same set of nodes, by simply keeping the coordinates of each node and randomly selecting the pairs of nodes to be connected. I knew of the many algorithms but none of them seemed to suit my needs, up to my knowledge.

Comment: what degree distribution?  Configuration Model seems the most likely option.  nx.configuration_model([1]*1000) will get you what you've stated you need, but it may not have all the properties you want.

Comment: I think the challenge I'm having understanding your question is that it's not clear what output you would want.  Let's say start = 0 end = 2.  Can you give a sample **full** output for this?  I'm interested in: How many "edges"? Is repetition of an edge allowed?

Comment: By the way, a common algorithm for interpolating between a lattice and a random graph is to start with a lattice and then select random pairs of edges `(u,v)` and `(w,x)`.  Then delete them and create new edges `(u,x)` and `(w,v)` (after checking that those edges don't exist already and u!=x, w!=v).

Comment: @Joel: I should really clarify this. The degree distribution will be "dictated" by the random selection of edges. The length distribution, instead, in the case of a lattice is a single value which occurrence equals the total number of edges, since all nodes are equidistant from each other.

Comment: @Joel: "repetition of edges" is a tricky concept. We should really talk about directed edges (from A to B) or undirected edges (from A to B and vice versa). In the latter case, yes, we are repeating the A to B edge. One of my goals is to build an undirected random network and then a directed one. As for the full output, I should have added an explanatory picture upon asking, which I will do shortly, so please check my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92435/discussion-between-joel-and-francesco-castellani).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the list creation you can do something like:

```
import random
max = 999
min = 0
original_values = range(min, max) # could be arbitrary list
n_edges = # some number..
my_edge_list = [(random.choice(original_values), random.choice(original_values)) 
                      for _ in range(n_edges)]
```

To assert you have all values in there you can do the following

```
vals = set([v for tup in my_edge_list for v in tup])
assert all([v in vals for v in original_values])
```

The assert will make sure you have the proper representation in your edges.  As far as doing your best to make sure you don't hit that assert you can do a couple of things.

1. Sample without replacement from your list of integers until they are all gone to create a "base network" and then randomly add on more to your hearts desire
2. Make n_edges sufficiently high that it's very likely your condition will be met.  If it's not try again...

Really depends on what you're going to use the network for and what kind of structure you want it to have

**EDIT:** I have updated my response to be more robust to an arbitrary list of values rather than requiring a sequential list

Comment: Because there is no need for an assert. It basically means the algorithm is broken.

Comment: I disagree with that...especially because option 1 ensures that that won't happen.  The OP did not specify how they wanted the network generation to occur, if they wanted it one attempt, if it needed to be a complete graph, etc.  The only stipulation was that every possible number was part of at least one edge.   Both proposed algorithms provide that

Comment: @haavee If I generate a random sequence of numbers, but do some steps to guarantee they have some property a priori, it's likely I'll be biasing my outcomes.  To have an unbiased sample in these cases, I should generate the sequence and then test.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar answer but for a complete graph on - [How to generate a fully connected subgraph from node list using python's networkx module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649673/how-to-generate-a-fully-connected-subgraph-from-node-list-using-pythons-network)

In your case, using [zubinmehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294714/zubinmehta)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651524/510937):

> ```
> import networkx
> import itertools
>
> def complete_graph_from_list(L, create_using=None):
>     G = networkx.empty_graph(len(L),create_using)
>     if len(L)>1:
>         if G.is_directed():
>             edges = itertools.permutations(L,2)
>         else:
>             edges = itertools.combinations(L,2)
>         G.add_edges_from(edges)
>     return G
> ```

You could build the graph as:

```
S = complete_graph_from_list(map(lambda x: str(x), range(0,1000)))
print S.edges()
```

Comment: If you copy content from an other question/answer you *must* (by the license) properly attribute it by stating who is the author (with a link to his profile) and what's the original question/answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I will keep in mind to also write the author's name if i'm going into referrals. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

Python has inbuilt library called **[itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)**.
Sample as below as how you achieve what you mentioned:

```
import itertools

list = [3, 4, 6, 7]
sublist_length = 2
comb = itertools.combinations(list, sublist_length)
```

This will return **comb** as an iterator.

You can do `comb.next()` to get next element in the iterator or iterate over a for loop to get all results as you wanted as below.

```
for item in comb:
    print item
```

which should output:

```
(3, 4),
(3, 6),
(3, 7),
(4, 6),
(4, 7),
(6, 7),
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a networkx command that will create a graph such that each node has exactly one edge:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.configuration_model([1]*1000)
```

If you look into the guts of it, it does the following which answers your question - each node will appear in **exactly** one edge.

```
import random
mylist = random.suffle(range(start,end))
edgelist = []
while mylist:
    edgelist.append((mylist.pop(),mylist.pop()))
```

You should guarantee that `mylist` has even length before going through the popping.

Comment: Well, I should have made this clear too. What I am after is a network in which every node appears at least once in the `edgelist`. In my conceptual models, no disconnected nodes are allowed. So, saying that each node will appear in exactly one edge means, for me, that all my nodes have just one link (e.g., their degree is always 1, no matter where they are located). Building a network like this will produce no disconnected nodes, but will also constrain the number of links, and could somehow be seen as the output of a constrained randomness. Makes sense?

Comment: So my main question is - how many links do you want?  Any algorithm that someone provides will enforce that the number of links comes from some distribution.  You should put some thought into how many links you actually want, and then it's much easier to create an algorithm to provide that.  Right now it's not clear if you want the bare minimum (what I've provided) or the maximum ( `nx.complete_graph(1000)` ) or somewhere in between.

Comment: Good point Joel. I refrained from adding all these details in the original question to avoid publishing a "bible". The random network features random connections, hence the number of links each node has must be random (*from 0 to x*), and so are the nodes to which it is connected. The answer is therefore somewhere in between, but according to a random process.

Comment: "somewhere in between, but according to a random process" isn't precise enough to give a good answer.  There are a huge number of different random processes that will produce an answer somewhere in between.  Given that you put a neural-network tag on this question, I'm assuming you're interested in a particular thing happening on this network and possibly comparing it to the lattice.  But it's going to be a bad comparison unless you make sure you're using the appropriate random network.

Comment: I checked this out. Somewhere in between translates into a random Gaussian number from 0 to 15. I am now wondering what is your knowledge regarding network theory, as there is something I might be missing. Could you please enumerate a list of random networks? Since I only know of two variants of the Erdos-Renyi model. In this regard, I am looking for the `G(n, p)` (or Gilbert, 1959) variant.

Comment: So an obvious network to think about is the small-worlds network.  From your lattice, use `nx.double_edge_swap` [link](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.swap.double_edge_swap.html) to swap edges randomly.  As you do this more and more, you'll get towards a completely random network with the same degrees.  This lets you interpolate between a lattice and the random network.  Alternately, go straight to the random network with `nx.configuration_model` (but read the documentation carefully since it can have self-edges or repeated edges).

Comment: If you want to be sure your final network is connected (rather than just every node has an edge), then look at `nx.connected_double_edge_swap`.

Comment: you are being extremely helpful! Upon approaching NetworkX I had guidance from a post doc fellow who told me this package wasn't very flexible. It now turns out it is flexible, at least as far as I am concerned. The only thing that worries me is "a completely random network with the same degrees". Do you mean that the degree distribution will remain exactly the same as the lattice?

Comment: Theoretically both the lattice and the (almost) purely random network follow a Poisson distribution in terms of degree distribution. The only difference is that the lattice displays a very high peak (which corresponds to links=4 - just think of how the lattice is built and of any node which is everywhere except on the lattice *boundary*), and it is a very concentrated distribution. In the random case, it should not be so straightforward for you to see this, and the degree distribution should be more spread out. Your thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for making it long @Joel, but this needs clarified. Upon switching from a regular Kleinberg lattice (https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/swn.d/swn.html) to a random network, the ending point of a given edge starting from a given point must be chosen **randomly from a uniform distribution**, as I want all nodes to be equally probable to be connected to the current node being analyzed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92600/discussion-between-joel-and-francesco-castellani).

Answer (score 0):

```
random.seed(datetime.datetime.now()) 

from random import randint
# ot generate 100 tuples with randints in range 0-99
li = [(randint(0,99),randint(0,99)) for i in range(100)]
print(li)

[(80, 55), (3, 10), (66, 65), (26, 23), (8, 72), (83, 25), (24, 99), (72, 9), (52, 76), (72, 68), (67, 25), (72, 18), (94, 62), (7, 62), (49, 94), (29, 89), (11, 38), (52, 51), (19, 32), (20, 85), (56, 61), (4, 40), (97, 58), (82, 2), (50, 82), (77, 5), (2, 9), (2, 46), (39, 4), (74, 40), (69, 15), (1, 77), (45, 58), (80, 59), (85, 80), (27, 80), (81, 4), (22, 33), (77, 60), (75, 87), (43, 36), (60, 34), (90, 54), (75, 3), (89, 84), (51, 93), (62, 64), (81, 50), (15, 60), (33, 97), (42, 62), (83, 26), (13, 33), (41, 87), (29, 63), (4, 32), (6, 14), (79, 73), (95, 4), (41, 16), (96, 64), (15, 28), (35, 13), (35, 82), (77, 16), (63, 27), (75, 37), (11, 52), (21, 35), (37, 96), (9, 86), (83, 11), (5, 42), (34, 32), (17, 8), (65, 55), (58, 19), (90, 40), (18, 75), (29, 14), (0, 11), (25, 68), (34, 52), (22, 8), (12, 53), (16, 49), (73, 54), (78, 80), (74, 60), (40, 68), (69, 20), (37, 38), (74, 60), (53, 90), (25, 48), (44, 52), (49, 27), (28, 35), (29, 94), (35, 60)]
```

Comment: It's a start, but this doesn't guarantee that every ID is present.

Comment: Yes John, and this is a crucial point. My ultimate aim is to build a network which has 10000 nodes, and for my goal it would be pointless having even a few disconnected nodes. So I must find a way to check for complete connectedness. And, of course, no self-linking is allowed (the starting and ending point of each parenthesis in the list must NOT coincide). Thanks for highlighting this!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution that first generates a random population of nodes (`pop1`), then shuffles it (`pop2`) and combines those into a list of pairs.

**Note:** this method only yields vertices where each node is exactly once `start` and exactly once `end`, so maybe not what you're after. See below for another method

```
import random, copy

random.seed() # defaults to time.time() ...
# extract a number of samples - the number of nodes you want
pop1 = random.sample(xrange(1000), 10)
pop2 = copy.deepcopy( pop1 )
random.shuffle( pop2 )
# generate pairs from the same population - this guarantees your constraint
pairs = zip( pop1, pop2 )

print pairs
```

Output:

```
[(17, 347), (812, 688), (347, 266), (731, 342), (342, 49), (904, 17), (49, 731), (50, 904), (688, 50), (266, 812)]
```

### Here is another method

This allows for duplicate occurrences of the nodes.
The idea is to draw `start` and `end` nodes from the same population:

```
import random
random.seed()
population = range(10) # any population would do
# choose randomly from the population for both ends
# so you can have duplicates
pairs = [(random.choice(population), random.choice(population) for _ in xrange(100)]
print pairs[:10]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 9), (7, 1), (8, 6), (4, 7), (6, 2), (7, 3), (0, 2), (1, 0), (8, 3), (8, 3)]
```

Comment: There is a bug in your first approach.  Try it with start=0, end = 1.  You'll get `(0,0)` `(1,1)` half the time, which violates the constraint requested.  More generally, a fraction for large values, you'll run into a node connected to itself in 1/e of the samples you generate.

Comment: Your second approach also as a bug.  As you can see in your output, `5` did not appear, which violates the constraint the OP gave.

Comment: Well, my the first method does satisfy those constraints. OP did not mention if nodes should appear more than once - i.e. in different edges.

Comment: The OP mentioned that they should be connected to other nodes.  I'd be shocked if a (1,1) edge meets the OP's requirements.

Comment: In graphs in general there's nothing that shouldn't allow nodes to connect to themselves but yes, OP has somewhat underspecified the problem.

Comment: Correct, a (1,1) edge is not allowed in my models. Nodes can be connected to any other node in the random network, but not to *themselves*.

Comment: Well, one other thing missing in your problem description is how many _edges_ you'd like. The nodes is one thing but if you look at the diagrams (thanks for those) there's 12 edges in the first and 17 (if I counted correctly ...) in the 2nd.