# Clique creation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

Is there a convenient way to create a clique out of a list of objects (such as strings) representing vertices, instead of generating each edge manually?

Comment: Note - I've added an edit showing how to modify `G` in place as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate of [How to generate a fully connected subgraph from node list using python's networkx module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649673/how-to-generate-a-fully-connected-subgraph-from-node-list-using-pythons-network), but I'm going to give a different answer than what is in there.

The approach is to generate a clique and then use networkx's method for relabeling nodes.

```
import networkx as nx
L=["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you"]
G=nx.complete_graph(len(L))
H=nx.relabel_nodes(G,dict(enumerate(L)))

H.nodes()
> ['how', 'are', 'world', 'you', 'hello']
G.nodes()
> [0,1,2,3,4]

nx.relabel_nodes(G,dict(enumerate(L)), copy=False) #you can also change G in place
G.nodes()
> ['how', 'are', 'world', 'you', 'hello']
```

Comment: I've added a line at the end to show how to modify `G` in place