# Color a subgraph

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I have a complete graph (all nodes are directly connected by an edge), and I want to color a subset of nodes and edges over the same graph. The complete graph for N=5 is this.

[N=5 COMPLETE GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMyYd.png)

Now I want to color, for example, the next subset of edges: [(0, 3), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 2)] in blue. How can I do that over the same graph?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `draw_networkx_*` functions to separately draw each part of the graph (nodes, node labels, edges, edge labels), you have fine control of what is rendered.  The main trick is to produce the positions dictionary and then reuse it for each drawing function.

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# produce a degree-5 complete directed graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
edges = itertools.permutations(xrange(5), 2) # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651524/1643946
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# specific path to highlight
elist =  [(0, 3), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 2)] 

# set up layout
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

# draw it
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color='k', width=0.5) # show all edges, thin lines
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elist, edge_color='b', width=2) # highlight elist

# turn off axis markings
plt.axis('off')
```

Produces a graph like this:

[image: complete graph with highlight]

Comment: I got very good results, but I would like to have the plot without the axes, is it that possible?. I have the same plot you have shown, but with axes.

Comment: Ah, yes - you just need to use `plt.axis('off')`, but note that needs an extra import as well.  I edited the example to show it